# A combinatorics puzzle related to Isserlis' theorem

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, puzzle, means, gaussian

The puzzle is as follows:
$$
\newcommand{\empty}{\phantom{1}}
\newcommand{\boxes}[2]{\boxed{#1}\hspace{-0.04cm}\boxed{#2}}
$$
**At iteration (1)** you start out with a pair of boxes, one empty and one with a 1:
$$
\boxes{1}{\empty}
$$
**At iteration $i$** do the following:

- Fill each empty box, creating a new term for each box you fill
- Then, add new terms corresponding to all of the terms from iteration $i - 1$, but with a $\boxes{i}{\empty}$ box tacked onto the end.

---

**Examples**: Iteration (2) would look like:
$$
\boxes{1}{2} + \boxes{1}{\empty}\:\boxes{2}{\empty}
$$
where we've added one term for the one empty box, and then tacked on $\boxes{2}{\empty}$ to the term from iteration (1). Iteration (3) would look like:
$$
\boxes{1}{3} \boxes{2}{\empty} + \boxes{1}{\empty} \boxes{2}{3} + \boxes{1}{2} \boxes{3}{\empty} + \boxes{1}{\empty} \boxes{2}{\empty} \boxes{3}{\empty}
$$
Here the first two terms come from filling the two empty boxes, and the last two terms come from tacking on a $\boxes{3}{\empty}$ to the end of the previous terms. Iteration (4) would look like:
\begin{multline}
\boxes{1}{3} \boxes{2}{4} 
+ \boxes{1}{4} \boxes{2}{3} 
+ \boxes{1}{2} \boxes{3}{4} 
+ \boxes{1}{4} \boxes{2}{\empty} \boxes{3}{\empty} 
+ \boxes{1}{\empty} \boxes{2}{4} \boxes{3}{\empty} \\
+ \boxes{1}{\empty} \boxes{2}{\empty} \boxes{3}{4} 
+\boxes{1}{3} \boxes{2}{\empty} \boxes{4}{\empty}
+ \boxes{1}{\empty} \boxes{2}{3} \boxes{4}{\empty}
+ \boxes{1}{2} \boxes{3}{\empty} \boxes{4}{\empty}
+ \boxes{1}{\empty} \boxes{2}{\empty} \boxes{3}{\empty} \boxes{4}{\empty}
\end{multline}

---

**Once you have done $n$ iterations** get rid of any terms which have an empty box. Here, iterations (1) and (3) would just give nothing, while (2) would give $\boxes{1}{2}$ and (4) would give:
$$
\boxes{1}{3} \: \boxes{2}{4} 
+ \boxes{1}{4} \: \boxes{2}{3} 
+ \boxes{1}{2} \: \boxes{3}{4}
$$
**How do you describe what you're left with at the end**?

I think this should end up being identical to [Isserlis' Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Isserlis%27_theorem), but I'm hoping to come up with a slick combinatorial proof given this formulation. I haven't been successful so far, and all of the proofs that I have found use results from statistics that I am not familiar with.